# asset versioning (js and css) and browser not pulling the most recent asset

Tags: html, css, symfony, versioning, assetic

I am currently using asset versioning on my symfony2 projects when ever I have a new update to the site, before doing assetic dump I changed the asset number first and then I ran

```
sudo php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

then I cleared the cache. However on my windows machine when I tried it still uses the old assets before the update and hence messing a lot of the layout. What is the best way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you you messed with `assets` and `Assetic` library. Assetic library gives you ability to process your css and js resources. And so `assetic:dump` is just processing your js and css files (minimizing it, compile many files in one or any other processing).

To make your assets be accessible you need to run `php app/console assets:install`. If you want it be always up to date with your Resources folder you can just add `--symlink` option to this command. It will create symlink `web/bundles/yourbundle` pointing to your `src/YourBundle/Resources/public`.